# How to list the files of a directory in Clean

Tags: clean-language

I need to list all files of a directory using the Clean programming language, but I don't know any function to do so. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function `getDirectoryContents` from the [`Directory` module](http://wiki.clean.cs.ru.nl/Directory), which is bundled with the Clean distribution.